# Center and Middle Align all cells in an Excel worksheet

Tags: powershell

I am using the ImportExcel PowerShell module to export data from a SQL server to an Excel spreadsheet.  I've got the entire process worked out but I would like to have the entire worksheet - Sheet1 as the default - to be both center and middle aligned.

I am looking at the FormatCellStyles examples listed in their Git but none make sense to me as how to apply these two alignments to the entire sheet.

[ApplyFormatInScriptBlock](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Examples/FormatCellStyles/ApplyFormatInScriptBlock.ps1)

[ApplyStyle](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Examples/FormatCellStyles/ApplyStyle.ps1)

[PassInScriptBlock](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Examples/FormatCellStyles/PassInScriptBlock.ps1)

The code is pretty straightforward until I get to the alignment issue - and I get stuck.  Is it possible to center and middle align an entire worksheet using the ImportExcel module?

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $sqlserver -Database $database -Query $query | Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors | Export-Excel -Path $ExcelFile -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the ImportExcel module often, but never for formatting so I decided to have a little fun and take on your challenge.  Unfortunately I did not find a way to apply the alignments using `Export-Excel` directly, however you can do the following afterwards to the saved workbook

```
$excelPath = 'C:\temp\formattest.xlsx'
$excel = Open-ExcelPackage $excelPath
$excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1'].Cells | Set-Format -HorizontalAlignment Center -VerticalAlignment Center
Close-ExcelPackage $excel
```

---

Looking over some of the examples you provided it looks like something like this may be the more expected approach:

```
$excelpkg = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $sqlserver -Database $database -Query $query | 
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors | 
        Export-Excel -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow -AutoSize -PassThru
$ws = $excelpkg.Workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1']
$wsUsedRange = $ws.Dimension.Address
Set-ExcelRange -Worksheet $ws -Range $wsUsedRange -HorizontalAlignment Center -VerticalAlignment Center
Close-ExcelPackage $excelpkg -Show -SaveAs $ExcelFile
```

- Passthru the output from `Export-Excel` to a variable,
- apply the changes you would like using `Set-ExcelRange`
- and then save and close the workbook using `Close-ExcelPackage`

Comment: Happy to help and learn a few things along the way!